# TypeScript + WebStorm unwanted typeof warnings

Tags: typescript, webstorm

What is the recommended approach today to dealing with TypeScript unwanted checks that pertain to use from JavaScript?

I have the following function:

```
function connect(config: string): void {

    // Getting warning for the line that follows:
    //     typeof check is always false: 'config' always has type 'string'

    if (typeof config !== 'string') {
        throw new Error('Connection config must be a string');
    }

    // execute normally...
}
```

I am using WebStorm UI, which pops up such warnings in a few places. The warning is irrelevant, because the module is compiled into JavaScript, and distributed as such, so the verification is strictly for calls from JavaScript clients. But there can also be TypeScript clients, so I cannot just change the function parameter type to `any` in the declaration.

What is the modern and recommended approach to getting rid of such warnings? Preferably, not in a way that disables such checks completely.

Comment: This feature was introduced to deal with similar issues and I believe you can leverage it here as well [ts-expect-error-comments](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-9.html#-ts-expect-error-comments)

Comment: @AluanHaddad Maybe similar, but not the same, it doesn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

After trying some suggestions here, I found it to be the easiest to do inline re-cast into `any`:

```
function connect(config: string): void {
    if (typeof config as any !== 'string') {
        throw new Error('Connection config must be a string');
    }
}
```

That way, any TypeScript client will be correctly required to pass in a string, while any JavaScript client will get an error thrown, if it passes in anything other than a string.

And we are no longer getting any of those `typeof` warnings.

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need check for the type of config since the compiler will
> throw error wherever you try to pass a non string config value to the
> function. ie, the check has to happen before the function call.

OR

If the config can be of any type and need to be checked, you need to define the function as follows

```
function connect(config: any)
```

As per your code the type of your config is always a string. So, the compiler error makes sense.

Comment: I have just added an update to my question, about use of `any` re-cast, but inline where the check is used. I wouldn't change the declaration to `any`, that's not a good idea, because there can also be TypeScript clients that will use it.

Comment: @vitaly-t usage of `any` is not usually preferred, but since you need a check and cater for the js calls, usage of `any` would be a valid usecase here. or you can just suppress the ts error using `@ts-ignore`

Comment: If you're going to do this, you might want to use an overloaded signature so that consumers know that users who have static analysis tools can know they're supposed to pass a string.